# Custom Slot decorator not working in PySide6 when connecting inherited event

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, signals-slots, pyside6

I had the following piece of code working fine in PySide2 project:

```py
def _my_slot(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = args[0]
        obj.activateWindow()
        obj.raise_()
        obj.setFocus()

    return Slot()(wrapper)
```

I could then use `@_my_slot` as a decorator around slots where I wanted to give back focus to the parent after they're executed.

I'm trying to migrate this project to PySide6, and this piece of code is not working anymore with the following error

```
AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtCore.MetaFunction' object has no attribute 'im_func'
```

any has an idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

This is a minimal example to reproduce, python 3.11, PySide6 6.6.0, windows:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot, Signal, QPoint


def _my_slot(func):
    """
    A decorator that adds focus and window activation functionality to slots.
    """

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        obj = args[0]
        obj.activateWindow()
        obj.raise_()
        obj.setFocus()

    return Slot()(wrapper)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    total_number = Signal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # if I comment the following line it works
        self.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.onContextMenu)
        self.total_number.connect(self.update_total_number)

    @Slot()
    def onContextMenu(self, point: QPoint):
        pass

    @_my_slot
    def update_total_number(self, total_number: int):
        self.total_number.emit(total_number)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication()
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: It may be a bug, but unfortunately your code doesn't give us enough context to understand the issue. Note that the `Slot` decorator always returns the *original* function, which is an important aspect to consider when dealing with garbage collection and QObject destruction. It is possible that some object gets destroyed in the meantime, but either the Python GC or Qt deferred deletion cannot keep up. Can you please provide a valid [mre] that properly works under PySide2 and fails with PySide6?

Comment: This is most definitely a bug in PySide6, because `im_func` is a purely Python2 instance-method attribute that was replaced by `__func__` in Python3. A work-around is to simply `return wrapper` and then decorate the method itself with both `@_my_slot` and `@Slot` (in that order). Or even just omit `@Slot`, which is redundant in 95% of cases anyway.

Comment: @musicmante @ekhmoro I added a minimal example, and located the problem to something that happens internally when connecting `customContextMenuRequested` of `QMainWindow`, I'm however struggling with getting an environment that lets me debug what's happening inside that connect function

Comment: I think it has to do with this:
https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside6/libpyside/qobjectconnect.cpp?h=v6.6.0#n109

I think this check has something outdated or mismatching with the slot creation, but I'm currently too lazy to get all that's needed to be able to debug this (^^ゞ.

for now I'm just calling a normal `_focus()` method at the end of those slots instead of a fancy decorator.

I'll leave the question open in case someone someday cares to solve it

Comment: @MysticOdin I already explained exactly what the bug is. There are numerous places in the PySide6 source like this: `PyObject_GetAttr(slot, PySide::PySideName::im_func())` - which is exactly equivalent to calling `getattr` in Python. In your example, if you do `getattr(self.update_total_number, "im_func")`, you will see it raises an equivalent exception: "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'im_func'". This is entirely as expected, since in Python3 the atribute name is `"__func__"` rather than `"im_func"`. The easy fix for your example is to omit the redundant `@Slot` decorator.

Comment: @ekhumoro that doesn't explain why it works with pyside2 _and_ python 3 though, also doesn't explain why it works if I comment that line

Comment: @MysticOdin It explains it all perfectly well. Obviously, PySide2 doesn't include all of the same buggy `PyObject_GetAttr` calls (which you can easily see by comparing the relevant sections of the source code). Commenting out that line simply means `connect` isn't called, which is where the buggy code is called internally by PySide6 (i.e. it calls [isMethodDecorator](https://code.qt.io/cgit/pyside/pyside-setup.git/tree/sources/pyside6/libpyside/qobjectconnect.cpp?h=v6.6.0#n20) after calling `qobjectConnectCallback`).